# Gerburtsname is ******** on Social Security Card

Tags: germany, social-security

I and my wife recently immigrated to Germany.

We recently received our social security cards from the Deutsche Rentenversicherung.

While filling all relevant forms, I had left "Geburtsname" empty for both me and my wife. My wife has not changed her name after marriage.

However, on my card, the “Geburtsname” has been mentioned as “Bond”. (which is same as my Nachname)

But on my wife’s card the “Gerburtsname” is mentioned as “********”. (just asterisks)

I was wondering why this is different for the both of us.

Could that be an issue in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [the specimen on their website](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/DRV/DE/Rente/Allgemeine-Informationen/Sozialversicherungsausweis/sozialversicherungsausweis_node.html), asterisks seem to be the default if there is no birth name different from the current surname. I'm not sure why this has been put in in your case, but it doesn't seem to be problematic.

There is also [another sample image](https://www.imacc.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Sozialversicherungsausweis-beantragen-L.jpg), which has birth name and surname identical.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering the same. Why would they put the Geburtsname in some and not in other. I've also used their contact form to ask the same, will report back here in case they reply!

Comment: Update! I had used their website's "contact-us" form to leave them a message regarding the missing Geburtsname. They did not respond to the message but I just received an updated social security card where the Geburtsname has been fixed!